# How to convert Zero to Nan in the array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, python-xarray

[image]

I used the `temp[temp==0] = np.nan`, but I got this Error:

> IndexError: 2-dimensional boolean indexing is not supported.

Comment: could you please let us know what you tried and what you want. Question must be more precise fro us to help

Comment: I want to convert zero value to Nan in the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `where`, to avoid having to drop down to numpy:

```
In [35]: d
Out[35]: 
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2, dim_1: 3)>
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0, dim_1

In [36]: d.where(d != 0)
Out[36]: 
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2, dim_1: 3)>
array([[nan,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.]])
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0, dim_1
```

and which will automatically move to floats if necessary.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @DSM Is there a way to perform this conversion by preserving the values as integers? I don't want them to be moved to float.